# Runtime.getRuntime().exec error=13 Permission denied

Tags: java

I get `Runtime.getRuntime().exec error=13 Permission denied` all the time when running the code below

```
String DIR_CODE="/home/users2/BNR/script/";
String FILE="lance_bnr.sh";


String[] cmdArray = new String[2];
cmdArray[0]=DIR_CODE;
cmdArray[1]=FILE;

Process p=null;
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray,null);
```

How could I do?

Comment: please show us the result of `ls -al /home/users2/BNR/script/lance_bnr.sh`

Comment: Try to provide the full path to your shell script.

Comment: @gfelisberto -rwx------ 1

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `exec(String[] cmdarray) Executes the specified command and arguments in a separate process.` But are sending the directory as the command and the script name as a parameter.

Try:

```
String[] cmdArray = new String[1];
cmdArray[0]=DIR_CODE + FILE;

Process p=null;
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);
```